# После закрытия окна WPF с dotnetbrowser растёт потребление озу

Tags: c#

не знаю как отловить утечку памяти
на тестах с главного окна запускается около 10 потоков, в каждом создаётся окно wpf с элементом браузера dotnetbrowser и выполняются действия на определённых сайтах, после завершения действий вызывается dispose объекта браузера и закрывается окно из кода, ожидает около 2мин и запускается сново поток. Сразу же после закрытия окна wpf в течении 30 сек может вырасти потребление ОЗУ с 3ГБ до 15-20ГБ, потом снижается до уровня перед закрытием окна.
Куда надо смотреть, чтобы найти исправление подобного?

код метода, который запускается в Thread:

```
public void Circle()
        {
            Instance instance = null;
            string key = "keyxxxx";
                string folder_program = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
                string end = new Random().Next(900000000).ToString();
                string folderbin = "engineTest" + end;
                string folder = "zapuskTest" + end;
                string file_geo = "coordinates clear.txt";
                string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("keys.txt");
                string WorkWord = lines[new Random().Next(lines.Length)];
                lines = File.ReadAllLines("proxy.txt");
                string Proxy = lines[new Random().Next(lines.Length)];
                Proxy = lockp.TakeProxy();
                
                
                int titanport = new Random().Next(11010, 12900);
                

                instance = new Instance(this, WorkWord, key, false, Proxy, null, titanport, folder, folderbin, "", 768, 1366, file_geo);
                //I = instance;
                AllInstance.Add(instance);
                string fullpathf = instance.FolderExist(folder);
                string fullpathfb = instance.FolderBinary(folderbin);
                
                try
                {
                    instance.GoToMap();
                }
                catch
                {
                    instance.TitanProxy.StopTitanProxy();
                    Console.WriteLine("Сбой ЗАДАЧИ------------------------------");
                }
                
                foreach (Tab t in instance.AllTabs)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (!t.browser.IsDisposed)
                        {
                            t.browser.Dispose();
                        }
                        
                        t.Clear();
                    }
                    catch
                    {

                    }
                }
                try
                {
                    while (!instance.engine.IsDisposed)
                    {
                        instance.engine.Dispose();
                        Thread.Sleep(5000);
                    }
                    
                }
                catch
                {

                }
                
                instance.ActiveTab.IW.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        instance.IW.Close();
                        Thread.Sleep(10000);
                        
                        
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("НЕ СМОГЛИ ЗАКРЫТЬ ОКНО-------------------------------");
                    }
                }));
                try
                {
                    instance.Clear();
                    Thread.Sleep(10000);
                    while (!instance.isDisposed)
                    {
                        instance.Clear();
                        Thread.Sleep(10000);
                    }
                    
                }
                catch
                {

                }
                AllInstance.RemoveAll(x => x.isDisposed || x == null);
                Thread.Sleep(30000);
}
```

код запуска потоков:

```
await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                int start = 0;
                int finish = 1000;

                List<Thread> allThreads = new List<Thread>();
                for (int f = 0; f < countTh; f++)
                {
                    Thread th = new Thread(Circle);
                    
                    th.Start();
                    allThreads.Add(th);
                    start++;
                    Thread.Sleep(15000);
                }
                while (start < finish)
                {
                    for(int h=0; h<countTh;h++)
                    {
                        if(allThreads[h].IsAlive)
                        {
                            Thread.Sleep(7000);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            allThreads.Remove(allThreads[h]);
                            //GC.Collect();
                            Thread th = new Thread(Circle);
                            th.Start();
                            allThreads.Add(th);
                            h--;
                            start++;
                            Thread.Sleep(60000);

                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Исходный код можете предоставить?

Comment: добавил код потока и запуска потоков

Comment: Если вы синхронизируете логику приложения с помощью `Sleep`, значит что-то пошло не так. Этот код надо переписать так, чтобы не осталось ни одной паузы. И почему вы в одно месте деоаете нормально `Task.Run`, а в другом начинаете возиться с потоками на низком уровне? Когда вы закрываете приложение, оно остается висеть в памяти?

Comment: пока я его не закрываю, тестирую как отрабатывают потоки и библиотека, которая потом будет использоваться, приложение пока для теста библиотеки, а не рабочее, Task.Run - запускается по клику на кнопку - запустить потоки, и внутри уже запускаются потоки и через паузу проверяются на завершение, чтобы поддерживать нужное количество потоков. Чем в данном случае плоха пауза?

Comment: Как минимум тем, что она вешает намертво поток. А пауза внутри `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` вешает всё приложение. Сейчас попробую переписать код запуска потоков, только разберусь в нем сначала. Кстати, `keys.txt` и `proxy.txt` - насколько большие это файлы, по сколько строк?

Comment: немного, не больше 20-30

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Использовать `Sleep` для синхронизации различных компонент приложения - плохо, потому что вы как минимум жертвуете поток на это ожидание. Как максимум вешаете все приложение, если этот `Sleep` находится в основном UI потоке.

Есть `SemaphoreSlim`, с помощью которого можно реализовать запуск любого числа задач с ограничением количества одновременно работающих.

То есть код запуска можно переписать вот так.

Добавить вот такой метод

```cs
public async Task StartCircleAsync(SemaphoreSlim semaphore)
{
    try
    {
        await Task.Run(() => Circle());
    }
    finally
    {
        semaphore.Release();
    }
}
```

Внешний `Task.Run` надо убрать, получится вот так.

```cs
int start = 0;
int finish = 1000;

List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
using (SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(countTh))
{
    for (int i = start; i < finish; i++)
    {
        await semaphore.WaitAsync();
                    
        Task task = StartCircleAsync(semaphore);
        lock (tasks)
            tasks.Add(task);

        _ = task.ContinueWith(_ => 
        { 
            lock (tasks) 
                tasks.Remove(task); 
        });
    }
    Task[] taskArray;
    lock (tasks)
        taskArray = tasks.ToArray();
    await Task.WhenAll(taskArray);
}
```

Вот я уже избавился от пачки `Sleep`.

Далее уберите все `Sleep` из UI потока, например вот этот

```cs
instance.ActiveTab.IW.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
{
    try
    {
        instance.IW.Close();
        //Thread.Sleep(10000);     
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("НЕ СМОГЛИ ЗАКРЫТЬ ОКНО: " + ex.Message);
    }
});
```

Он совершенно ничего не делает и никак вам не помогает, только вешает приложение. При этом пока выполняется `Sleep` окно остается открытым и закроется оно только после того как приложение отвиснет после сна.

Далее, файлы `keys.txt` и `proxy.txt` можно прочитать один раз при старте приложения в нужные структуры данных и потом просто использовать эти уже прочитанные данные.

`new Random()` создаете 4 раза, создавайте один раз.

```cs
Random rnd = new Random();
string end = rnd.Next(900000000).ToString();
string WorkWord = lines[rnd.Next(lines.Length)];
string Proxy = lines[rnd.Next(lines.Length)];
int titanport = rnd.Next(11010, 12900);
```

Далее, после вызова `Dispose` объект нельзя использовать, вообще никак и никогда

```cs
if (!t.browser.IsDisposed)
{
    t.browser.Dispose();
}
                        
//t.Clear();
```

Далее, вот этот страшный цикл

```cs
while (!instance.engine.IsDisposed)
{
    instance.engine.Dispose();
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
}
```

Содержит ту же самую проблему, переписать вот так

```cs
if (!instance.engine.IsDisposed)
{
    instance.engine.Dispose();
}
```

Далее, вот этот фрагмент, обрабатывайте ошибки правильно, хотя-бы сообщайте себе, что за ошибка произошла.

```cs
try
{
    instance.GoToMap();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    instance.TitanProxy.StopTitanProxy();
    Debug.WriteLine("Сбой ЗАДАЧИ: " + ex.Message);
}
```

Как вы уже поняли, класс `Console` не следует использовать в отладочных целях в графических приложениях, используйте для вывода в `Output` окно студии класс `Debug`.

Чтобы копать дальше, надо знать подробнее внутреннюю структуру вашего приложения и его назначение. В любом случае, после применения рекомендаций, озвученных выше, должно стать лучше.

Comment: спасибо, Ваш код понятен, буду править!

Comment: единственное, впервые вижу - _ = task.ContinueWith(_  , что означает подчёркивание?

Comment: [ContinueWith is Dangerous, Too](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/continuewith-is-dangerous-too.html)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov для того чтобы удалить элемент из листа сугубо фиолетово, какой там шедьюлер подцепится, но я не самом деле не знал. Хотя по идее в своих проектах я вообще не использую континуации, там просто логика проектируется так, чтобы в них не было потребности. А здесь оно как самое простое решение, как мне кажется, подошло.

Comment: @АрхиповВладимир https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/discards

Comment: @АрхиповВладимир исправил небольшой недочет, вызов `Task.WhenAll` не был потокобезопасным, теперь все ок. Шанс сбоя был не велик, но был.

Comment: Огромное Спасибо!!!

Comment: @АрхиповВладимир как там с памятью, помогло?

Comment: да, помогло, не растёт как было при закрытии окна, очень доволен)